# Is there any way to retrieve password hashes from an Active Directory via LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, passwords, password-hash

I know one can retrieve password hashes via RPC (ms-drsr), like it's done in the [DSInternals PowerShell Module](https://github.com/MichaelGrafnetter/DSInternals/blob/master/Documentation/PowerShell). Is there any way to get the MD4 hashes via LDAP?

So far I've tried using the AdDirSyncRequest control (1.2.840.113556.1.4.841), but with no luck.
I can see the password attributes (ntPwdHistory, unicodePwd, etc) but they have no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. The `unicodePwd` attribute is used to set the password, but [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2) says:

> The unicodePwd attribute is never returned by an LDAP search.